# iOS Development - Using rootViewController correctly

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have been learning iOS development for a few days now. At this moment, I have questions over how the rootViewController is to be used. I searched the web for 3 hours yesterday looking for the answer which turned up quite a few results that never really answered my question.

I am trying to learn to program an app using code only (no storyboards/xib files). I currently am trying to understand how to properly switch between views without using the UINavigationController. In my project I have the main delegate which creates the window, initializes my main view controller (which loads the separate view as well) and adds it as the rootViewController.

My first view has a button which calls a function in its controller to switch to my next view. Here is where my question arises: Do I switch the main rootViewController to the next view or do I load the next view as a subview of the rootViewController? Is the rootViewController supposed to encase all the views for an application? (I think this is how the UINavigationController works)

I have gotten switching of the rootViewController to work in my app, but I want to make sure there isn't some other way I am suppose to manage my views.

Comment: "_I am trying to learn to program an app using code only (no storyboards/xib files). I currently am trying to understand how to properly switch between views without using the UINavigationController._" - why? Storyboards and xib files are central to iOS development, you need a pretty good reason to avoid them. Same goes for navigation controllers. If you're just starting out, start out properly.

Comment: I don't like using anything that writes code for me, especially when learning. It feels like I am not properly learning how the application works if things are done automatically for me. I intend to use storyboards and xib files when I understand objective-c and the iOS frameworks better.

Comment: That is a common and fundamental misunderstanding of what storyboards and interface builder are for. They don't write any code for you. Good luck though, you're definitely thinking about things properly and asking sensible questions here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not switch the rootViewController, I think that should remain stable.  So you could add it as a subview, or you can present it as a modal view.

And of course, you can just change the rootViewController to point to your new view if that's how you want to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. To me, switching the rootViewController feels dirty. The word root is what makes me want to keep it stable as you said. I just didn't want to clutter up the rootViewController with other views that might not be related to it, but I guess that is where using modal views comes in I think.

Comment: Yeah, I think modal views are the way to go if you don't want to use one of the frameworks provided (storyboard, NavigationController, etc.).